# How to pass argparse argument to a sanic route?

Tags: python, sanic

I wish to pass an argparse argument to a function with decorators. What is the strategy here? How can I achieve this without global variables?

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from sanic import Sanic, views, response
import os
import argparse

app = Sanic(__name__)

@app.route('/<var:var>')
async def get(self, request, var):
    print(path)
    return response.text(var)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--path",
                        help="Set the server root path",
                        action="store")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

I also tried using the view `HTTPMethodView` but without success

Comment: what's the purpose and what's the benefit? that args are parsed just once at application start, but routes can be requested any times. Moreover, `/<var:var>` is treated as query param passed in url in scope of http request

Comment: I want to setup a root path at start from which to display a list of files

Comment: why don't use `os.path.dirname(__file__)` ?

Comment: I want some flexibility on this

Comment: I've updated my answer to make it flexible and not use environment variables or globals, give it a try! I don't have a laptop at the moment!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you could dynamically change the function for that route based on the parse arguments... Like this (sorry I'm on my phone)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 
from sanic import Sanic, views, response 
import os 
import argparse 

app = Sanic(__name__)

@app.route('/<var:var>') 
async def get(self, request, var): 
    print(path)
    return response.text(var) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--path", help="Set the server root path", action="store")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    def get(var):
        # use args.p in your route function!!

    app.view_functions["/<var:var>"] = get
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

Might be some mistakes but you should get the gist of it